# Open cv scratch detection

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, detection

I have an image with no scratches and another with scratches on it.
I want to compare these two. The output should be how many scratches there are on the second image. Is it possible to use opencv in ios (objective-c) platform?

Comment: Is image 2 (except for the scratches) the same image as image 1?

Comment: yes both are same image

Comment: Please post the images

Answer (score 3):

You could just use `image3 = image2 - image1` this will remove the background and results in an image which only contains scratches (foreground). Then try to use `connectedComponents` to count the scratches.

Comment: Do you have a working example for this approach? Would be really helpful